# can i switch back to my normal android(the one provided by the phone) again after using ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was going to install ubuntu touch on my redmi 4x phone, and was wondering how am I going to switch back to android, Is it even possible to get to the original android which was installed on the first day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there's nothing with Ubuntu Touch that prevents that, the installation method however doesn't depend on Ubuntu Touch, it will be something that maybe your smartphone vendor can help you with.

Note, that the UBports Installer, now supports more than one Operating System, and if the community contributes with more configurations and images for other operating systems, it will actually be able to install other Operating Systems. As of today, the UBports Installer besides Ubuntu Touch can install install LineageOS on the OnePlus 2, more options of third party OS for more devices are expected to come for more devices, like VollaOS on the Volla Phone, etc...